# What is the best method to transmit a DVI-D video signal from a FPGA?

Tags: fpga, hdmi, lvds

I need to transmit a video signal from a FPGA. It will be better if this signal is some kind of standard protocol like DVI-D.

There is an [article](https://www.fpga4fun.com/HDMI.html) that proposes to use LVDS transmitters for TMDS lines. There are also some articles which state that FPGA LVDS drivers are often too weak to drive TMDS lines because of DC pull-up. So I am trying to find a TMDS transmitter.

I looked at the TFP410. This IC serializes a parallel CMOS to a serial TMDS, but the TFP410 takes quite a lot of FPGA output pins. I also tried to find a LVDS-to-TMDS converter.

- A [solution](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/f/138/t/712681?TFP401A-Convert-LVDS-to-DVI) from Texas Instruments is deserializing LVDS to CMOS with something like DS90C386, and then serializing CMOS to TMDS with TFP410.
- A [solution](http://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/JL/Lattice71VDSVideoDemoKitUsersGuide.ashx?document_id=22732) from the Lattice is the same.

These solutions require two ICs and quite a lot of PCB space to parallel CMOS lines. The ITE has a IT6263, LVDS-to-HDMI converter, but it's kind of weird.

There are some single LVDS-to-CML converters (actually, very few) like SN65CML100 and ADCMP606. Unfortunately each of this convertors costs as much as one TFP410.

What is the best method to transmit a DVI-D video signal from a FPGA?

Comment: Best depends on what FPGA you have and what interfaces on it you can use, and also what video bandwidth you need.

Comment: Have a look for open source implementations, this has some discussion of the driver issue: https://github.com/hdl-util/hdmi/

Comment: @Justme
Let it be for example 1080p, 60fps, MAX-10 10M04 with 7 hard LVDS transivers.

Comment: I like this kind of clarifying question :) - How to make X using Y in common case? - Oh! It depends on several conditions! - <Describing common case conditions.> - Well hmmm...

Comment: Why not just go for the VGA display? If you need something more powerful then looking reference designs will be great. If you are using Intel/Altera FPGAs then you could check out how the reference designs using HDMI or DVI-D have been created by Terasic. I know Terasic does have some boards with HDMI but am not sure about DVI-D.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 For the "HDMI Transmitter Daughter Card" Terasic uses the IT6613E IC. It's an analog of the TFP410 from ITE. The IT6613E has same wide input CMOS bus. But prodution of ITE does not distribute on Digikey, Mouser e.t.c. So I think not every demoboard is good example to replicate. The VGA output needs three ADC with parallel input buses. The differenсe between VGA and HDMI is that VGA can provide less resolution and less common nowadays. So I think if I must use a wige CMOS output it is better to use CMOS-to-HDMI.

Comment: Max 10 won't be fast enough for that, surely? The LVDS transmitters top out at 720Mbps. 1080p@60fps would need 1390Mbps per lane. External parallel to serial is likely the only option for that res

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the Analog device IC ADV7511 cheap and best approach, which is capable of converting parallel digital pixel 24 bit RGB data from FPGA (LVCMOS) to RGB TMDS serial lines. But all the 24 bit lines should be length matched with respect to Clock, hsync and vsync in order to avoid skew.

Also do you have any requirement on output resolution. If output resolution requires 4K this is not suitable. This IC will support only up to 2k.

Reference schematics already available for this in Xilinx Kintex-7 (KC705), ZC706 based development kit.

Hope this helps.